# Вывод подобия прогрессБара в консоль

Tags: swift

В приведенном примере строка появляется не посимвольно с интервалом в секунду, а вся сразу через 5 секунд

```
for _ in 1...5 {
    sleep(1) // задержка между появлениями точек
    print(".", terminator: "")
}

print("end");
```

Как сделать, чтобы текстовый символ (в текущем примере - точка) в консоли появлялся друг за другом в одной строке с некоторой задержкой?

Comment: print(".", separator: "", terminator:"")

Comment: где тут задержка между появлением символов?

Comment: Так у Вас же есть уже эта часть: sleep(1) ?

Comment: в примере и terminator есть. Но вопрос совсем в другом. если скопировать код в плейграунд, станет понятно (ну или внимательно прочитать текст)

Comment: Вы хотите это в playground?

Comment: да, хочу в консоли выводить в строку символы через некоторый интервал времени

Comment: да, именно в playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD: С отключением буфера работает корректно в playground, попробуйте:

```
var counter = 0
setbuf(__stdoutp, nil)
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    guard counter < 5 else {
        print("End")
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }
    print(".", terminator: "")
    counter += 1
}
RunLoop.main.run()
```

---

Пример кода для playground:

```
var counter = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    guard counter < 5 else {
        print("End")
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }
    print(".", terminator: "")
    counter += 1
}
RunLoop.main.run()
```

Используем таймер, каждую секунду делаем print и увеличиваем счетчик. Если нужные условия выполнены, прекращаем.

Но проблема в том, что при отработке в playground появляется все сразу по окончании.

> . . . . . End

Если убрать terminator и делать только `print(".")`, то точки корректно распечатываются столбиком в консоли.

> .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   End

Если взять этот же код и запустить на симуляторе/устройстве, то отрабатывает корректно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, это просто баг в playground. Ваш вариант без terminator тоже отработает в playground, но в программе все повесит на 5 секунд.

Comment: вы переписали код из примера, при этом усложнив его ) Однако, я не знал, что в симуляторе/на девайсе оно работает корректно. Спасибо ) Но, да, нужно каким-то образом получить такое же поведение в плейграунде.

Comment: @xhr обновил ответ, попробуйте.

Comment: спасибо,  VAndrJ  )